# Whats the Script/Code to Kill CMD?

Tags: cmd

Well, the title pretty much says it all. I'm trying to kill cmd with a code, please help?
Much appreciated.

Comment: use this sample , you can use exit command to kill cmd. 


Microsoft Windows [Version 6.1.7600]
Copyright (c) 2009 Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

C:\Users\082043>**exit**

Comment: Please explain the actual scenario. so that I can give you proper solution

Comment: Public Class Form1
    Private Sub Button2_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
        Process.Start("CMD.exe")
        SendKeys.Send("C:\batchfile.bat")
    End Sub
    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    End Sub
End Class

Answer (score 0):

```
  Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        p1 = Process.Start("C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe")
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button2_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
        p1.Kill()
    End Sub
```

Comment: You can run the Bat file using this, If you want to stop Bat operation , just use <processVaribe>.kill(); please let me know if you have any issues.

Comment: I don't understand the code? My batchfile isn't for a website link. That's why i'm confused yo, sorry.

Comment: you can put anything in you BAT file, am just using sample, to demonstrate to stop the CMD from Code. just give me the sample BAT, so taht Ican Update you with the Answer

Comment: hey dude, I need to get the BAT file script contents. Please use my code, you can try with ur sample bat file

Comment: if you convert the batchfile.bat into a batchfile.txt it says cd desktop cd edm world game bot cd game bot node edmworldgamebot.js

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with please tell me the requirement, the requirement does not sync with ur last comment, Please send your requirement..

Comment: I'm beyond confused yo, lol.. all i want is to close cmd out after it's been started. i have an on button and an off button.

Comment: Please check the Updated answer. try this.. you can put what ever exe to start to Stop using this code, only thing you need to change the exe path

Comment: Ohhhhh god .. can u please check the code... in ur app.. how many times i explained you...

Comment: I literally don't understand what you're asking for.. you're making no sense to me as much as i'm making no sense to you? i've shown you the code already.

Comment: Kill(), function will stops the Process the which u started. waht ever it may be CMD, notePAd, you can able to Stop process by Kill()

Answer (score 0):

From the "Examples" section of `taskkill /?`:

```
TASKKILL /F /IM cmd.exe /T
```